# Limit of the variance of a difference of indicators

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

Consider a sequence of $n$ iid random variables $Y_i$ having a density with respect to Lebesgue measure at $0$, $g(0)$. Compute the following limit:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \text{Var} \left [\sum_{i=1}^n \int_0^{\eta/\sqrt{n}} \left ( 
\mathbb 1(Y_i \leq s) - \mathbb 1(Y_i \leq 0)
\right) ds\right ]$$

where $\eta$ is some real valued constant.

**my attempt**

Since the $Y_i$ are iid we can rewrite this as:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} n\text{Var} \left [ \int_0^{\eta/\sqrt{n}} \left ( 
\mathbb 1(Y_i \leq s) - \mathbb 1(Y_i \leq 0)
\right) ds\right ]$$

Now, substituting $u = \sqrt n s$:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \text{Var} \left [ \int_0^{\eta} \left ( 
\mathbb 1(Y_i \leq u/\sqrt n) - \mathbb 1(Y_i \leq 0)
\right) du\right ]$$

But since the expression inside the integral goes to $0$ pointwise (since $Y_i$ has a density at $0$), we have that the integral also goes to $0$ (applying dominated convergence). Then, since the variance of a term that goes to a constant goes to $0$, we have that the entire expression evaluates to $0$.

Have I made any incorrect assumptions or manipulations here?

Answer (score 1):

The following provide a method to calculate the variance what you want. Let
\begin{align*}
 Z_i&=\int_{0}^{\eta/\sqrt{n}}(1(Y_i\le s)-1(Y_i\le0))\,\mathrm{d}s\\
       &=\int_{0}^{\infty}1(0< Y_i\le s\le \eta/\sqrt{n})\,\mathrm{d}s\\
       &=\Big(\frac{\eta}{\sqrt{n}}-Y_i\Big)^+, 
\end{align*}
then $\{Z_i,1\le i\le n\} $ is a sequence of iid random variables and
\begin{align*}
 \mathbb{E}[Z_i]&=\int_{0}^{\eta/\sqrt{n}}\Big(\frac{\eta}{\sqrt{n}}-Y_i\Big)^+ g(y)
 \,\mathrm{d}y\\
                &=\int_{0}^{\eta/\sqrt{n}}\Big(\frac{\eta}{\sqrt{n}}-Y_i\Big)^+ 
                (g(0)+O(y))\,\mathrm{d}y\\
                &=\frac{g(0)\eta^2}{2n}+O(n^{-3/2})\\
 \mathbb{E}[Z_i^2]&=\frac{g(0)\eta^3}{3n^{3/2}}+O(n^{-2})\\
 \mathsf{Var}[Z_i]&=\mathbb{E}[Z_i^2]-(\mathbb{E}[Z_i])^2\\
                  &=\frac{g(0)\eta^3}{3n^{3/2}}+O(n^{-2})
\end{align*}
Hence,
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathsf{Var}\Big[\sum_{i=1}^{n}Z_i\Big]=0. 
\end{equation*}